# nginx proxy configuration to server with dynamic ip addresses

Tags: nginx, proxy, amazon-route53

I am working on AWS and using an EC2 instance for CI operations and more particularly for Jenkins. This server lies behind an nginx server which is used as a proxy for requests to ci.domain.com

Everything is working fine until a failure occurs on the CI server.

Once that happens, another instance boots up, upserts its IP to the DNS service pointing the new IP to ci.domain.com

The problem is that I need to restart the nginx service in order to discover the CI server again. Before that I get 5xx Bad Request or Timeout responses.

Below is part of my nginx configuration concerning the particular upstream server:

```
upstream jenkins {
    server ci.domain.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=100s;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ci.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_pass http://jenkins;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;

        # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server see `resolve` flag

Comment: @AlexeyTen resolver in combination with set $jenkins "http://ci.domain.com"; just worked for me. Apparently nginx is treating variables a different way than static declarations.

Comment: In that case you actually do not use `upstream` at all

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes I had to remove upstream and add a resolver and a variable inside the CI server block.

Comment: Variables in `proxy_pass` makes it behave differently. See docs on `proxy_pass`